# I am making a script in roblox studio but i am getting the message Expected identifier when parsing expression, got '='"

Tags: get, message

here is the code :

local speedcircle = game.ServerStorage:WaitForChild("speedcircle")

local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

game.ReplicatedStorage.Speed.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, CFrame)
local character = player.Character

```
--weld humanoidroot part to speed part
local HRP = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local speed = speedcircle:Clone()
speed.Parent = workspace
speed.Anchored = false
speed.CanCollide = false


local weld = Instance.new("Weld")
weld.Parent = speed
weld.Part0 = speed
weld.Part1 = HRP
weld.C0 = HRP.CFrame = HRP.CFrame.p = Vector3(0,3.1,-0.2)


character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 60
wait(1)
character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 80
wait (1)
character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 100
wait (2)

character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 20
```

end)

Answer (score 0):

(Might need to be comment.) Copy and post the FULL error in a comment on this answer. I need the full error message, as it normally tells you what line the error happens at.

Comment: 16:23:26.603  ServerScriptService.speedScript:21: Expected identifier when parsing expression, got '='  -  Studio - speedScript:21 | that's the full message I hope it helps

Comment: i forgot to say this but the error line is this ||||| weld.C0 = HRP.CFrame = HRP.CFrame.p = Vector3(0,3.1,-0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, I realized my stupid mistake lol. 99% postitive you CAN do this = this = this.
Your issue is at `Vector3()`. That's not how you declare a vector3. Use `Vector3.new()` instead.
Sorry for any confusion created by my incorrect previous comments..